# Parsing HTTP Authorization header with multiple values?

Tags: rest, groovy, http-headers

i am creating a rest api in which there is a need for transferring the apikey and a signature in the http headers. Now i can supply the required parameters inside the http header and a controller reads it out nicely but i was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

We transfer the values of the apikey and sha1 signature in the HTTP Authorization header and retrieve this by using.

```
request.getHeader("AUTHORIZATION").split(',').
        inject([:]) { map, token ->
            token.split('=').with {
                map[it[0]] = it[1]
            }
            map
        }
```

The result is a map which contains the key/value pairs

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Hi Marco, having the same issue right now - did your code prove successful? Did you find a better way? -- Jan

Comment: @JanAlgermissen at the end we modified the stuff to use a authorization header such as: <appname>:apikey:timestamp:signature so we skipped the use of the '=' sign. Now our code just checks if the http request has a "AUTHORIZATION" header and split the values using .split(':')